# Does anyone know of a node.js library to speak to Arduino over network?

Tags: arduino, arduino-yun

Does anyone know of a node.js library to speak to Arduino yum internally (not over serial to pc)?

basically like Johnny-five plugin or Cylon.js plugin but that will me to run node.js on the yum and talk to the micro controller, all using node js JavaScript?

Thanks,

Sean.

Answer (score 0):

It has already been done by Tigoe...

A simple Google search got me there, I guess you were feeling lazy.

[Here it is](http://www.tigoe.com/pcomp/code/arduinowiring/1216/)...